# Can't connect to github.com at all

Tags: github, https, connection

I'm running windows 10. I used to use github just fine and I'm not sure what changed, but I can't access the site in any way. I can't browse it. I can't use github tools. I've tried http and https. It all times out.

All other https sites work fine. All other sites that I can find in general work fine. It's just me and Github not getting along.

I beseech thee, code gurus, help me get back to work.

I've tried setting myself in the DMZ of my router and turning off the firewall, to no effect.

Comment: Just in case it helps, here's a screenshot of my router firewall page: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sllbclx4d8nhgm5/Screenshot%202016-12-28%2019.44.04.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, the issue may have been with GitHub itself. If you go to https://www.githubstatus.com/ you can get the real time status for all GitHub services.

I only found this today because I had the same issue you described here. Turns out, it's because of an outage on GitHub's end.

Answer (score 0):

are you about to connect to this ip?

192.30.252.153
192.30.252.154

[You should get this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn8S6.png)

Comment on whether you get this or not you get this so I can help you

Comment: I browsed to both of these and got that page.

Comment: For sake of being thorough, I tried with https:// in front and received the same result. No delay in connecting to that error page.

Comment: I tethered my computer to my phone and could connect. This is hardly ideal. What broke that would cause this fail with this one site?

Comment: the DNS data could have broke.

sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder; say cache flushed - clear DNS cache on mac

ipconfig /flushdns - clear DNS cache on windows

Comment: It just occurs to me, if this was a break on my computer, tethering to my phone would not fix it. DNS can't be the issue, can it?

Comment: run this
`ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: I did attempt that, several times. No effect.

Comment: hmmmm I am lookinng into a fix

Answer (score 0):

It went away as mysteriously as it came. We may never know.